# How to perspective with Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I need to change between the original controls and someones to change the perspective with the corners like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxKqx.png)

At this moment I take this with the original controls, but I need to swap between the two options, teh originals and somones t ochange the perspective with the corners

```
function uploadImage() {
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("uploadForm"));
    fetch("process.php", {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData
    })
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(data => {
        document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = data;
        var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("preview_canvas");
        canvasContainer.innerHTML = "";
        var newCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        newCanvas.id = "canvas";
        newCanvas.className = "mt-4 border";
        canvasContainer.appendChild(newCanvas);
        canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', { backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)' });
        var imgElement = document.getElementById('uploadedImage');
        fabricImg = new fabric.Image(imgElement, { left: 0, top: 0, selectable: true });
        var backgroundImageUrl = 'image.jpg';
        fabricImg.set({ skewX: parseFloat(document.getElementById('skewRange').value) });
        fabric.Image.fromURL(backgroundImageUrl, function(img) {
            canvas.setDimensions({ width: img.width, height: img.height });
            canvas.setBackgroundImage(img, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
        });
        canvas.add(fabricImg);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error en la petición fetch: " + error.message);
    });
}
```

Comment: What did you end up doing about this? Could you share your solution? Thanks